# TortoiseSVN Repo-Browser urls

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

How do I remove the urls of repositories that no longer exist in the dropdown in the TortoiseSvn repo-browser?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just move the mouse over the item you want to remove and press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>.

Answer (score 4):

Open regedit

go to hkey_current_user\software\tortoisesvn\history\repourls\

change the urlX value to "" for whatever you want to delete.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to your Program menu and find TortoiseSVN > Setting

There is "Saved Data" tab. From there you can remove all of the items in the list which may be more than you wanted to get rid of.  I'm not sure where this is stored and if there is an option for removing individual items.